# Yield keyword can not be used in ref struct?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.2

I would like to use `yield` in ref structure method:

```
public ref struct RefStruct 
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 1;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the error:

> CS4013 Instance of type 'RefStruct' cannot be used inside a nested function, query expression, iterator block or async method

But the instance of `RefStruct` is not used in the iterator block.

I can assume that `yield` translation rules have not changed for ref structures. As in classes, method with `yield` is translated into `GetEnumerator` class, which has field that stores an instance of ref struct. This is incorrect since the class field cannot be ref struct. But in this case, the compiler must complain about another error.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The compiler decided to create keep a copy of `this` in the generated enumerator class anyway: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQAYACfARhQG4BYAKHwGZiBnAFygFcxXiAlGAGYBldlx50A3nWIzSTAJIBRAHYcAtjCgBDVtAA8AS2WsAfMQDiMVivWad0ABQBKabKm1Zn0mTKkA7MRkNB6yAL50oUA===)

Comment: @conton7 You're missing the ```ref``` keyword there.

Comment: @imsmn That's deliberate: with `ref`, you get a compiler error, and so can't see the decompiled output (obviously). Leaving off the `ref` lets you see what the compiler generates for a normal struct, which includes storing the struct in the generated iterator class. You can then infer that it's trying to do the same for the ref struct.

Comment: @canton7 Ah, okay. I thought it wasn't intentionally. My bad.

Comment: [The spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/span-safety#language-constraints) tries to cover this case, but I think technically the wording omits it. It forbids a ref struct local from being in scope when a `yield return` occurs, but doesn't consider that `this` can also be in scope, and be a ref struct. If anything, a little doc update is all that's needed. [I raised a doc issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/18922)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's going on, but after some playing around I found the following work around, maybe it is useful

```
public ref struct RefStruct 
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Foo();

        IEnumerator<int> Foo()
        {
            yield return 1;
        }
    }
}
```